# Flink project doesn't detect dependencies in IDE

Tags: git, maven, apache-flink

I am trying to add code into the Flink Github repo and pulled a local copy of it to make the change to. However, my IDE is unable to detect the datastax dependencies or the slf4j dependencies and marks the import statements in the code as "Cannot Resolve Symbol...".

Running clean and install, validate, verify, and package (with the tests active) for the module, and everything runs just fine. But still the IDE says the libraries aren't present. Am I missing something?

And I haven't made any changes to the code yet, just pulling it in for the first time.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing that "fixed" this was I made a github fork of the project and cloned that locally. So exactly the same, but for some reason this has no problem with the dependencies.